# How can I remove all extraneous spaces from a *.docx file?

Tags: c#, formatting, docx, spaces, novacode-docx

I want to remove all superfluous spaces from a .docx file. If there are cases where there are more than two, to accomplish this manually I need to do a search-and-replace for two spaces multiple times to get all of them, and it's hard to tell when I'm "finished."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code, using the docx library, accomplishes it:

```
private void RemoveSuperfluousSpaces(string filename)
{
    bool superfluousSpacesFound = true;
    using (DocX document = DocX.Load(filename))
    {
        List<int> multipleSpacesLocs;
        while (superfluousSpacesFound)
        {
            document.ReplaceText("  ", " ");
            multipleSpacesLocs = document.FindAll("  ");
            superfluousSpacesFound = multipleSpacesLocs.Count > 0;
        }
        document.Save();
    }
}
```

Download docx from [here](https://docx.codeplex.com/).